# (Python) How do you reduce/get rid of the edge of an item inside a clearcut image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, alpha

I am having some issues with an image clearcutting tool I am building using the REMBG python library.

The output (RGBA -> converted to RGB) I am getting has a noticeable outline (usually grey) from the initial background removal process as indicated in the image below.
[image]
In order to combat this, I have tried using alpha matting (which creates artifacts when used) and also blurring the output edges through OPEN_CV (Does not fully remove the edge). I was potentially thinking that erosion may be a good fix for this but I am running into an issue where applying erosion would dilute the color on the entire image.

Could anyone please assist with sample code or suggest a way in which I can remove/ reduce the gray outline while keeping the rest of the image untouched?

Comment: The gray looks like bad anti-aliasing from using a blur process. Without the alpha channel, it is harder to process. Once could threshold on pure white. Then use morphology to dilate out the white by the thickness of the gray. Then put that mask back into the alpha channel. But that would leave a jagged edge.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight on this topic! The image was originally an RGBA output (corrected q for this sorry) - do you have any further suggestions in this case?